# How to use wildcard in action name of xml configuration in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, wildcard, struts

Here in a simple package I am having different URL patterns,  but for only URL pattern (`*.htmlx`) want to call action and interceptor.

How to use wildcard in action name. I tried but it doesn't work.

```
<package ....... >
<action name="*.htmlx" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.LoginAction1">
call a interceptor
/*.........
...........
*/
</action>

<action name="*.html" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.LoginAction2">
/*.........
...........
*/
</action>


<action name="*.jspx" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.LoginAction3">
/*.........
...........
*/
</action>

</package>
```

Comment: "htmlx" is the action extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use action extension in action mapping as an action name, you should sort this out by defining struts action extension in the `struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="htmlx,,"/>
```